# curl proxy tor "[warn] Invalid hostname [scrubbed]; rejecting"

Tags: ubuntu, curl, proxy, tor

I am executing this request through tor:

```
curl -v --socks5-hostname "127.0.0.1:9200" "http://myoniondomain.onion"
```

and I get this error:

```
[warn] Invalid hostname [scrubbed]; rejecting
```

I've tried this on tor 0.2 and on tor 0.4 versions on ubuntu

I didnt found a solution to overcome this? can you give me any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on tor version 0.2.9.14. It doesn't seem to support v3 addresses. But after upgrade to Tor version 0.4.8.0-alpha-dev everything worked fine. e.g. this command "curl -v --socks5-hostname "127.0.0.1:9050" "http://yq5jjvr7drkjrelzhut7kgclfuro65jjlivyzfmxiq2kyv5lickrl4qd.onion" gives me torproject site.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).